# How to I get the below code to work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have the below code working in vanilla JS, nothing too major just a simple change of colour for a group of boxes. It works all fine, but how would I recreate this in jQuery? I have included what I think should work though the addClass() function doesn't seem to work. Is it done correctly or am I just missing something incredibly obvious?

```
boxes.forEach((box) => {
  //Adds a click event to each box
  box.addEventListener('click', function () {
  //Sets active variable to the element which contains the class
  let active = this.classList.contains('box-active');

  //Goes through all elements again and removes the class/style needed
  boxes.forEach((box) => box.classList.remove('box-active'));

  //If the variable has the class remove it - if not add it
  active
  ? this.classList.remove('box-active')
  : this.classList.add('box-active');
  });
});`

`$('.box').each((boxIndex, box) => {
  $(box).on('click', () => {
  console.log($(box), boxIndex);
  let active = $(box).hasClass('box-active');

  //Goes through all elements again and removes the class/style needed
  $('.box').each((boxIndex, box) => {
    $(box).removeClass('box-active');
  });

  //If the variable has the class remove it - if not add it
  active ? $(box).removeClass('box-active') : $(box).addClass('box-active');
  });
});`
```

Comment: You don't need to `each` over a jQuery selection, to assign an event handler to each element. `$('.box').on('click', ...)` already achieves the same. Same goes for `removeClass`

Comment: And `let active = $(box).hasClass('box-active');` simply becomes `let active = $(this).hasClass('box-active');` then.

Comment: `$('.box').each( .. removeclass` -> `$(".box-active").removeClass(".box-active")`  (or `$(".box.box-active").removeClass..` if you're really going to add `box-active` to anything other than a `box`)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/  `active ? removeClass : addClass` -> `$(this).toggleClass("box-active", active)`

Comment: Worth a read: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work`     the `box` inside the click event handler is not the same `box` as when the click handler was assigned (which is your issue with addclass not working).  Your js code uses `box` but it's it's a different variable (with the same name) but not in the jquery click handler.   Use `'click', function() { $(this)...`   (this won't work in that way with `() =>` handlers, so you'd need to use `e.eventTarget`

Comment: (not sure why I added that as code rather than a link: can't edit old comments: [question about closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work))